# Trying to find median

Tags: sql, postgresql

While executing the query to find median I stumble upon this error message- BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`median`.`row_asc` - `median`.`row_desc`)'

[image: Table]

The query that I wrote:

```
with median as
(select lat_n, row_number () over (order by lat_n asc) as row_asc,row_number () over (order by lat_n desc) as row_desc
from station
 
 )
 select round(avg(lat_n),4)
 from median
 where abs(row_asc-row_desc) <= 1
```

While doing the same kind in postgresql by creating the table

```
create table station (id serial primary key,
                      city varchar(50),
                     state varchar(50),
                     lat_n float,
                      long_w float)
                      
insert into station values 
(2,'ctc','odisha',31.546,33.213),
(3,'khorda','odisha',30.546,39.213),                  
(4,'puri','odisha',41.546,37.213);  

with median as
(select lat_n,row_number() over (order by lat_n) as row_asc,
row_number() over(order by lat_n desc) as row_desc from station

)

select round(avg(lat_n),4)
from median
where abs(row_asc-row_desc) <=1
```

the error:

```
ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 7: select round(avg(lat_n),4)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: Do not post 2 different problems in one question.

Comment: change this : round(avg(lat_n)::numeric,4), for the round of avg issue

Comment: Sund'er thanks man it helped could you explain it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function requires the first argument to be of type `numeric`:

```
\df round
                         List of functions
   Schema   │ Name  │ Result data type │ Argument data types │ Type 
════════════╪═══════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════
 pg_catalog │ round │ double precision │ double precision    │ func
 pg_catalog │ round │ numeric          │ numeric             │ func
 pg_catalog │ round │ numeric          │ numeric, integer    │ func
```

and there is no implicit cast from `double precision` to `numeric`:

```
                         List of casts
   Source type    │ Target type │ Function │   Implicit?   
══════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════
 double precision │ numeric     │ numeric  │ in assignment
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html), only implicit casts are considered:

> **Function Type Resolution**
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Look for the best match.
>
> a. Discard candidate functions for which the input types do not match and cannot be converted (using an implicit conversion) to match.

So you will have to add an explicit cast:

```
round(CAST (avg(lat_n) AS numeric), 4)
```

Comment: Thanks man it helped got the desired output could you send link to the doc about the above cast functions. Also while the code works in postgresql but while executing it in mysql it  gives                                                                                                                    error-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'numeric), 4)
from median
where abs(row_asc-row_desc) <=1'. Is there any deviation in mysql environment?

Comment: I have added a quote from the documentation. Type casts are standard SQL, I refuse to point to documentation for them. There are many deviations in MySQL, but since I don't know it well, I cannot give you advice there.